# Search Facebook Graph API for long posts?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to search the Graph API for posts a Facebook member has written where post.length > n ?

Or would I have to pull posts and parse/filter them in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/) to make filtered Graph API calls.

This query will get you posts with a message containing the word "this" which are more than 50 characters long.

```
SELECT message, post_id FROM stream WHERE CONTAINS("this") and strlen(message) > 50 LIMIT 100
```

The `CONTAINS()` function is not documented. From my experimentation with it, it searches multiple fields and is optimized to return matches that are based on full names.